# how to scan more than one word in ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class WC {

    private ArrayList<String> note;

    public WC() {
        note = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        WC w1 = new WC();
        w1.note.add(input.next());
    }

}
```

but it won't scan more than one word

what should I do?

Comment: Enclose the  statements to take the input in a loop.

Comment: @davidxxx is right. You seem to be beginning your coding journey. You should check out "for" and "while" loops. Anyone used right should fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

Use Loop for taking Input and storing multiple times

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    WC w1 = new WC();

    // variable amount is number of times you want to enter data
    int amount = 5;
    for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
        w1.note.add(input.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zabuza amount is not given

Comment: You can input amount from user using input Scanner object

Comment: Therefore you may use `int amount = input.nextInt();`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    WC w1 = new WC();

    String str;
    while (!(str = input.next()).equals("quit")) {
        w1.note.add(str);
    }
}
```

This way, you can just type quit and it will stop the loop